# Python http server - can't read cookie

Tags: python, http, cookies, server

I've made python server and i'd like to create, send and receive cookies. I have problem with receiving them, when I visit it on Chrome I can see cookie was created. I've read that it should appear in os.environ but it never does. Here's my code:

```
import os
import time
import Cookie
import BaseHTTPServer
from multiprocessing import Process
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(s):
        #creating cookie
        c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        c['api'] = 'token'
        c['api']['expires'] = 3*60*60

        s.send_response(200)
        #sending cookie
        s.wfile.write(c)
        s.wfile.write('\r\n')
        s.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        s.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        s.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        s.end_headers()

        #reading cookies
        if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ:
            cookie_string = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
            c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
            c.load(cookie_string)
            try:
                data=c['api'].value
                print "cookie data: "+data
            except:
                print "The cookie was not set or has expired"
        else:
            print 'The cookie was not set'


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpd = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 8666), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

After I visit my site cookie is being created but there's never HTTP_COOKIE in os.environ.

Comment: I found solution. I replaced everything under #reading with s.cookieHeader = s.headers.get('Cookie')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For future readers:**

here's how you parse cookies in python3:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        cookies = SimpleCookie(self.headers.get('Cookie'))

        # then use somewhat like a dict, e.g:
        username = cookies['username'].value
```

---

**To answer OP's question:**

The problem is that you are looking for the cookie in the wrong place.
With the following lines, you check in your computer's operating system environment variables if one is named `HTTP_COOKIE`:

```
if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ:
    cookie_string = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
```

But there is no reason that running a python server would create an operating system wide environment variable.

Instead, you must look inside the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` that you are deriving from.
The correct way to access the cookies is the following:

```
cookie_string = s.headers.get('Cookie')
```

which will parse the headers sent by the client and give you the corresponding cookie string.